# Animation hangs when pushing UIViewController to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a custom UITableViewCell I created entirely in code. This project doesn't use autolayout at all, all drawing is done in code. When the user taps a button in my custom cell it calls a delegate which the UITableViewController implements and then pushes a new view controller to the navigation controller. It works fine, but when it's transitioning the animation freezes half way and then segues all at once as seen in this gif.
[image] I've worked on projects using storyboards and know it's not supposed to look like this. I've tried using dispatch_after and dispatch_async which lead to the same outcome. This is the code I'm using.

```swift
let vc = UIViewController()
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

How can I fix this bug? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can't view gif, please reshare or modify permissions. Or, even better, use the image uploader in the editor to inline it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I moved the gif to be inline

Comment: You haven't given us enough information. Are you using custom push/pop animations? There's no way for us to reproduce this as it stands.

Comment: No custom push/pop animations. I am literally just calling those 2 lines of code from a UITableViewController and that is precisely why this bug has been troubling me for multiple hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug is weird beyond understanding, but inserting the following line of code in the viewDidLoad of the viewController being shown fixed it.

```swift
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: I think I've figured out why this works. I believe it's because the vc being pushed on has a clear background color by default, so even though it's technically covering up the vc preceding it, you can still see it. This, coupled with the differing speeds (old vc goes off the screen slower than the new vc pushes on) causes the animation to look profoundly broken.

Comment: Excuse me, sorry, the `backgroundColor` property is NIL by default, not clear.

Comment: I honestly feel like this is Apple trying to punish people for not using Storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the view controller being pushed is a UITableViewController and the table view is hidden in the lifecycle at some point.

Look for `tableView.isHidden = true` in one of the overridden `viewWill...` or `viewDid...` methods and remove that line.